# Get PagerSlidingTabStrip page title onPageSelected

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm trying to get the selected page title from a PagerSlidingTabStrip to display on a toast. The page titles are generated from a dynamic list. I am able to get the current page position to display on a toast using:

```
         tabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Page position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

How can I get the current/selected page title?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own adapter for the PagerSlidingTabStrip(this is a viewpager right?) that will manage the titles and also positions.

```
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter vpAdapter;
```

**In mainActivity**

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        vpAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 2, this, clock, history);
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int nTabs;
    private Context context;
    private Fragment fragment1, fragment2;
    private CharSequence[] titles;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int nTabs, Context context, Fragment fragment1, Fragment fragment2) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragment1= fragment1;
        this.fragment2= fragment2;
        this.context =context;
        this.nTabs = nTabs;
        titles = new CharSequence[]{context.getText(R.string.Title_tab1), context.getText(R.string.Title_tab2)};
    }




    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return fragment1;
            case 1:
                return fragment2;
            default:
                return fragment1;
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return nTabs;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }
}
```

**and don't forget to set the adapter on the viewpager**

```
viewPager.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
```